# How can I use a dynamic to find out when a property is used?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I would like to find out which of the properties in a source input object, a method has used. After executing the method I need to store in a database which of the properties was used.

The input could be any class with simple types, like this:

```
public class MyData : IMyData
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public decimal C { get; set; }
}
```

I thought it could be done using an interface as input to the method, so I can replace the original object with a more advanced object, which stores usage of properties

```
public interface IMyData
{
    string A { get; }
    int B { get; }
    decimal C { get; }
}
```

I can then

1. Create a dynamic object with the same properties
2. Use ImpromptuInterface to simulate the dynamic object implements my interface
3. Call my method with this dynamic interface

   ```
   private static void Main()
   {
       var data = new MyData { A = "Test", B = 3, C = new decimal(1.2) };

       IDictionary<string, object> replacementObject = new ExpandoObject();
       replacementObject.Add("FieldsUsed", new List<string>());
       foreach (var property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
           replacementObject.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(data));

       var replacementInterface = replacementObject.ActLike<IMyData>();

       DoStuff(replacementInterface);
       Console.WriteLine($"The method used these fields {string.Join(", ", (List<string>)replacementObject["FieldsUsed"])}");
   }

   private static void DoStuff(IMyData source)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"A is {source.A}");
       if (source.B > 5)
           Console.WriteLine($"C is {source.C}");
   }
   ```

In the above example I would like to store that fields A and B have been used.

Only I am stuck at how I should store when a property is used by my DoStuff method.

Comment: There are crude debugging techniques to figure out if you get into a property, such as expanding the get/set and adding a line you can breakpoint on.  You can then breakpoint at DoStuff, turn on your property breakpoints, and see if they are hit or not.  I'm curious _why_ you want to do this, and why you want to use ExpandoObject; this does smell like an XY problem (as @Christopher mentioned in his answer).

Comment: Thanks Sean. This is not for use when debugging. This is for use in a live application. My input could be a Bloomberg Finiancial Data record, or a SIX record or something else. After having executed DoStuff, I need to store in a database which of the fields in a Bloomberg Financial Data record was used to DoStuff.

Comment: No problem, this extra context helps clarify for others.  Maybe you should specify in your question that you want to know which properties are used _at runtime_, since it wasn't clear to me from the way you phrased the question.  It could be read as just wanting to know if the properties are used at all (at compile time only).  The context of why you want this information helps us figure out your intentions.

Comment: I have ammended the text. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a wrapper like this:

```
public class ClassWrapper<T>: DynamicObject where T:class
{
    private readonly T _obj;
    private readonly List<string> _fieldsUsed=new List<string>();
    public ClassWrapper(T obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = _obj.GetType().GetProperty(binder.Name);
        _fieldsUsed.Add(binder.Name);
        result = propertyInfo.GetValue(_obj);
        return true;
    }
    public List<string> GetFieldsUsed() => _fieldsUsed;

    public T GetWrapper()
    {
        return this.ActLike<T>();
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
 var data = new MyData { A = "Test", B = 3, C = new decimal(1.2) };
 var mc=new ClassWrapper<IMyData>(data);

 IMyData wrapped = mc.GetWrapper();

 DoStuff(wrapped);
 Console.WriteLine($"The method used these fields {string.Join(", ", (List<string>)mc.GetFieldsUsed())}");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know when a property is used, a Interface like [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) can do that for you at runtime. The exampel is only about notification for writes (that actually changed a value), but it would be trivial to expand it to reads and writes. It is not a perfect thing of course, as different executions might follow different code paths that use different properties.

If a function takes a specific type as input, you have to asume that *all properties may be relevant*. This is especially true for abstract types and interfaces - often the interface *exists* for this function. If it is one of those two, you can also always provide your own implementation of those Interfaces and Abstract class.

I can not shake the feeling that this is a XY problem.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. That would require that I have access to, and can change implementation of the Get properties on the original object. In my example that would be the MyData object. I don't have that. This is for a library which can take any object as input.

Comment: @TorbenNielsen You are going to "replace the original object with a more advanced object" anyway. Just always use the proper version!

Comment: You lost me? Yes I am replacing the original with a more advanced version. And I need to create that dynamically, as my library has no idea what the source looks like. And you are right, that basically I would like the Get property to do some kind of notification. Only I can't figure out how to make a more advanced Get property on my dynamic object

Comment: @TorbenNielsen You got a Interface you are implementing. You do not need to need to implement it at runtime. Just implement the inferace you **know** is used at compile time???